# T-SQL Len function not working as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server (2008 R2 if that matters)

When I execute

```
select LEN('test')
```

I get 4 as expected

But now try this:

```
declare @s varchar
set @s='test'
select LEN(@s)
```

And the result is ... 1

How does it actually work?

Answer (score 5):

That is because if you were to

```
SELECT @s
```

it would return

```
t
```

only. You need to specify the length.

From [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/8671)

Comment: Thanks! I would never expect this

Answer (score 5):

When you define this:

```
declare @s varchar
```

you get a `varchar` of **exactly one character length** .

There's absolutely nothing wrong with `LEN`!

What you need to do is **specify an explicit length** when you define your `varchar` variable

```
declare @s varchar(20)
set @s='test'
select LEN(@s)
```

Now you should get back 4 from `LEN`  ...

Note: it is a **recommend best practice** to always specify a **length** when you use `varchar` - otherwise you'll run into these kind of surprises. ....

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare it as nvarchar with more than 1 char
try this, it works:

```
declare @s nvarchar(100)
```